# How to get all the historical data from chainlink price feeds?

Tags: chainlink

I wanted to pull the historical data stored by the [reference data contracts](https://feeds.chain.link/) by chainlink oracles. Since all the data is on-chain, I should be able to view it all? But currently, my contract can only see the latest answer. Any thoughts?

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/dev/AggregatorInterface.sol";

contract ReferenceConsumer {
  AggregatorInterface internal ref;

  constructor(address _aggregator) public {
    ref = AggregatorInterface(_aggregator);
  }

  function getLatestAnswer() public returns (int256) {
    return ref.latestAnswer();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view the entire history of reference contracts, you'll want to use the `getPreviousAnswer` method below, and input how many answers back you'd like to go.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/dev/AggregatorInterface.sol";

contract ReferenceConsumer {
  AggregatorInterface internal ref;

  constructor(address _aggregator) public {
    ref = AggregatorInterface(_aggregator);
  }

  function getLatestAnswer() public returns (int256) {
    return ref.latestAnswer();
  }

  function getLatestTimestamp() public returns (uint256) {
    return ref.latestTimestamp();
  }

  function getPreviousAnswer(uint256 _back) public returns (int256) {
    uint256 latest = ref.latestRound();
    require(_back <= latest, "Not enough history");
    return ref.getAnswer(latest - _back);
  }

  function getPreviousTimestamp(uint256 _back) public returns (uint256) {
    uint256 latest = ref.latestRound();
    require(_back <= latest, "Not enough history");
    return ref.getTimestamp(latest - _back);
  }
}
```

Comment: this will only work for the current aggregator phase and wont let you go all the way back to the first round

Answer (score 0):

I've written a library that lets you get the prev() or next() roundId from a given roundId:

https://github.com/JonahGroendal/chainlink-round-id-calc/blob/master/contracts/ChainlinkRoundIdCalc.sol

You can use prev() to go back all the way to the very first round if you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Update September 2022**

You can now easily view historical price data by using
[checkthechain](https://github.com/fei-protocol/checkthechain).

Below is a [minimal working example](https://ctc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/basic_usage.html) using the Python package:

```py
from ctc.protocols import chainlink_utils

feed = '0x31e0a88fecb6ec0a411dbe0e9e76391498296ee9'

data = await chainlink_utils.async_get_feed_data(feed)
```

Alternatively, you can also use their [API](https://ctc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/basic_usage.html).