# Chainlink historical price for AggregatorV3Interface

Tags: chainlink

Similar to this question [How to get all the historical data from chainlink price feeds?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84804/how-to-get-all-the-historical-data-from-chainlink-price-feeds)
I would like to retrieve the historical data of a particular price feed to be used off-chain for a large number of consecutive updates. However, according to the docs it seems like the round IDs are no longer incremental (i.e. you can't just call `getRoundData(latest_round-_step)` for steps in a certain range).

Is the solution to simply do a linear search backwards and try all entries smaller than the latest roundID, or is there a recursive way to achieve this right now (is the previous round ID saved somewhere)?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the solution to simply do a linear search backwards and try all entries smaller than the latest roundID

Basically, the answer to this is yes.

A better way would be to use the Graph to index the data feeds and then pull from the graph.

Comment: alright thanks, do you happen to have any resources at hand which I can read up on?

Answer (score 0):

The roundId is calculated from the phase and aggregatorRoundId:

```
function addPhase(uint16 _phase, uint64 _originalId) internal pure returns (uint80)
{
    return uint80(uint256(_phase) << PHASE_OFFSET | _originalId);
}
```

Since we know how the roundId is generated we can move through only the valid ones, no searching required.

I made a library for getting the next() and prev() roundId from a given roundId. You can check it out here https://github.com/JonahGroendal/chainlink-round-id-calc/blob/master/contracts/ChainlinkRoundIdCalc.sol

Answer (score 0):

**Update September 2022**

You can now easily view historical price data by using
[checkthechain](https://github.com/fei-protocol/checkthechain).

Below is a [minimal working example](https://ctc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/basic_usage.html) using the Python package:

```py
from ctc.protocols import chainlink_utils

feed = '0x31e0a88fecb6ec0a411dbe0e9e76391498296ee9'

data = await chainlink_utils.async_get_feed_data(feed)
```

Alternatively, you can also use their [API](https://ctc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/basic_usage.html).